# Software to balance sound levels and quality for iPhone

Tags: itunes

Is there software that will balance the sound level of the songs on my iPhone so that all the songs are at the same sound level and quality?

Answer (score 1):

The "Sound Check" feature will ensure all your songs play back at approximately the same volume. In iOS 5, tap Settings -> Music -> then switch Sound Check to ON.